# Strategies for safely free-ing values in a linked-list structure in C

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, free, c99

Using C I'm storing a large amount of data in a linked list structure. Some items in the linked list point to the same malloc'd data and this is causing issues when it comes to free-ing the linked list structure. I could solve the issue by copying the data as it's inserted into the linked list structure, but this has bigger implications for my program.

That said: the fact that I'm running into this issue suggests I have a design problem. As such, I'm looking for strategies and suggestions to help deal with this problem.

Here's some code that highlights the issue (and yes, I know that I shouldn't be blindly casting `malloc` like this):

```
char *val = (char *)malloc(256);
strcpy(val, "Dummy value");

LinkedListItem *itemB = (LinkedListItem *)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListItem));
itemB->value = val;
itemB->next = NULL;

LinkedListItem *itemA = (LinkedListItem *)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListItem));
itemA->value = val;
itemA->next = itemB;

LinkedListItem *cur = itemA;
while(cur)
{
    free(cur->value); // the crash will occur here, when performing a double free on itemB's value pointer
    cur->value = NULL;

    cur = cur->next;
}
```

I've seen many references to a 'safe' version of free that essentially NULL's the pointer after free-ing it, like so:

```
void free_generic(void **pp)
{
    assert(pp);

    if(pp != NULL)
    {
        free(*pp);
        *pp = NULL;
    }
}

while(cur)
{
    free_generic(&cur->value);
    cur = cur->next;
}
```

But this seems to have no effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: `free_generic(&cur->value);` ?? Do you allocate memory to `&cur->value` ?? Is it a pointer ?

Comment: sizeof(256) == sizeof(int) is probably too small for your string.

Comment: FYI, the `free_generic` does not work here because it sets the *pointer* to NULL, not the "pointee". So another pointer that points to the same location will still be pointing to it.

Comment: regarding: `sizeof(256)`,   '256' is an integer, so the sizeof operator will (for a 32 bit architecture) return 4, so the associated malloc will return 4 bytes.  This is probably not what you intended

Comment: when calling the system functions `malloc()` and/or `calloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding this line: `strcpy(val, "Dummy value");`  Because the prior malloc() onlt allocated 4 bytes, the call to strcpy() is writing past the end of the allocated memory, thereby corrupting the heap data structure.   This is undefined behaviour and is the root cause of the crash when calling free()

Comment: The sizeof(256) used in the malloc was simply a copy-and-paste error. I've edited it away. And yes, of course you should always check the return value of a malloc call. Again: this was just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what reference-counting is for.

Use this struct every time you allocate something:

```
struct AllocatedStringValue {
    char* string;
    size_t refCount;
};


struct AllocatedStringValue value;
value.refCount = 0;
value.string = calloc( 256, sizeof(char) );

LinkedListItem *itemB = (LinkedListItem *)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListItem));
itemB->value = value;
itemB->next = NULL;
value.refCount++;

...

itemA->value = value;
value.refCount++;

...

while(cur) {
    if( cur->value.refCount > 0 ) {
        cur->value.refCount--;
    } else {
        free( cur->value->string );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding this code snippit.

```
void free_generic(void **pp)
{
    assert(pp);       // this and following 'if' are testing same thing
                      // and this assert() should never fail as
                      // 'pp' is the address of a variable

    if(pp != NULL)    // could only fail if variable located at address 0
                      // should be: 'if( *pp )'
    {
        free(*pp);
        *pp = NULL;
    }
}

while(cur)
{
    free_generic(&cur->value);
    cur = cur->next;
}
```